# how to select all emails from specific email addres with microsoft graph api

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I followed the example given from this site:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/python-tutorial

I am trying to get all messages that are coming from a specific email address.

Following the example, I think I need to edit the query_parameters code. I've done that like this:

```
query_parameters = {'$top': '30',
                      '$select': 'receivedDateTime,subject,from',
                      '$search': '"=from:someperson@mail.com"',
                      '$orderby': 'receivedDateTime DESC'}
```

It gives me an error because it's not returning anything in the call.

Has anybody had success in altering the example to only return results from a specific email address?

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the following set of query parameters successfully in the project from https://github.com/jasonjoh/python_tutorial.git

```
  query_parameters = {'$top': '25',
                      '$select': 'receivedDateTime,subject,from',
                      '$search': '"from:some.user@mycompany.ccTLD"',
                      }
```

The orderBy query parameter does not appear to be supported with search -- output when I attempted to add it:

```
messages    
('400: {\r\n'
 '  "error": {\r\n'
 '    "code": "SearchWithOrderBy",\r\n'
 '    "message": "The query parameter \'$orderBy\' is not supported with '
 '\'$search\'.",\r\n'
 '    "innerError": {\r\n'
 '      "request-id": "1416dd7c-81o4-4b52-953d-ab23c0933be9",\r\n'
 '      "date": "2018-10-02T11:30:12"\r\n'
 '    }\r\n'
 '  }\r\n'
 '}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `=` to your `$search` phrase. The `=` character is added automatically by the SDK. As it is written, your query parameter ends up as `$search="=from:someperson@mail.com"` rather than the intended `$search="from:someperson@mail.com"`.

```
query_parameters = {'$top': '30',
                    '$select': 'receivedDateTime,subject,from',
                    '$search': '"from:somepersotn@mail.com"'}
```

Also, you cannot specify a sort order when using `$search`. From the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#search-parameter):

> The results of the search are sorted by the date and time that the message was sent.